# Wordpress not connecting to database with nginx, letsencrypt, and docker compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a VPS setup with debian 10 and looking to add multiple wqordpress sites using docker compose. I am using nginx and letsencrypt in separate containers...and that part seems to be working. I get the SSL and can ping the site, WP wont connect to the database though and I have a feeling I am missing something simple...I'm a newb with docker and compose

here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"

services:
   db_domain:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
        - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Password1234
        MYSQL_DATABASE: domain-db
        MYSQL_USER: domainUser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: otherPassword1234
     container_name: domain-db

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
        - db_domain
     image: wordpress:latest
     expose:
        - 80
     restart: always
     environment:
        VIRTUAL_HOST: domain.com
        LETSENCRYPT_HOST: domain.com
        LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: admin@domain.com
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_domain:3306
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: domainUser
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: otherPassword1234
     container_name: domain-wp
volumes:
  db_data:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues: The environment variables for the Mysql service are not setup properly and the Wordpress service is missing the WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: domain-db environment variable.
Here is a configuration that comes up without DB errors:

```
version: "3"

services:
   db_domain:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
        - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password1234
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=domain-db
        - MYSQL_USER=domainUser
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=otherPassword1234
     container_name: domain-db
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
        - db_domain
     image: wordpress:latest
     expose:
        - 80
     restart: always
     environment:
        VIRTUAL_HOST: domain.com
        LETSENCRYPT_HOST: domain.com
        LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: admin@domain.com
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_domain:3306
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: domainUser
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: otherPassword1234
        WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: domain-db
     container_name: domain-wp
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: This definitely got me pointed in the right direction, thank you...it was still failing to connect to the DB, after checking the docker logs for that container it was restarting and failing, so I switch to using mariadb image instead of the mysql one...that one would come up correctly but still not connect. The logs are showing access denied for the DB user. The passwords are the same, I even dropped them to super simple passwords for testing. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Not sure I understand where you are seeing the error now. What are you seeing? I run docker compose up and I do not see any errors when the containers are coming up. The one thing I forgot to mention is that the environment variables for user and pwd are only evaluated the first time the DB comes up. So if you changed them on the docker-compose, then you need to delete the db_data folder in your local before bringing the container up after the change.

Comment: When you say delete the db_data folder in my local...is that on the host machine? I have been removing the containers each time and bringing them back up fresh with each iteration I am trying. this is the error I see in the container log 2020-05-02  2:55:19 17 [Warning] Access denied for user 'user'@'172.19.0.6' (using password: YES)

Comment: Yes, delete the db_data on the host, otherwise it will not re-evaluate the values of the environment variables for user and pwd. These are set only when the database is initialized the first time (which is what populates the db_data folder). After that those variables are ignored

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this `WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: domain-db`.

And the WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD must to be equal to MYSQL_PASSWORD.

Anyway, RTFM -> https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

Best regards.

Comment: Definitely been reading up...so I added the WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: and confirmed that the passwords are the same, still not connecting to the DB.

Comment: Try to remove the port in -> WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_domain:3306. Or just use the example in dockerhub, it works.